# Postman API Tests

Tags: postman

I have a response body like

```
{
  "agreementId": "agreement900",
  "Status": "ONHOLD"
}
```

The value of the status can be one of
`['PAID','CANCELLED','COOLINGOFF','ONHOLD','COOLINGOFF','PAID']`

I need to write a generic test to verify that the body.Status is always among the specified array.

I tried something like this

```
var data = ['PAID','CANCELLED','COOLINGOFF','ONHOLD','COOLINGOFF','PAID'];

pm.test("Verify Body value", function () {
  let testResult = data.find((each)=>{
    pm.expect(each.payoutStatus).to.equal(jsonData.payoutStatus)
  });
});
```

But received the following error:  `Verify Body value | AssertionError: expected undefined to equal 'ONHOLD'`

Comment: Make sure to read through: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
and to check some examples of top questions in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes

Comment: does this help addressing your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deepak, welcome to SO

I am not sure about edge cases nor performance, but this can be a way of achieving it:

```
var myStatus = pm.response.json().Status;
var myEnum = ['Pig','Chicken','Cow'];
pm.test("Status belongs to the ENUMs", function () {
    pm.expect(myEnum).to.include(myStatus);
});
```